# Set up AlwaysOn in virtual environment: How to add nodes to domain?

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustering

On a beefy server, I have a few Virtual Machines (VMs) running. On one of those, I have Domain Controller (DC) with a domain name (ex:SQL.AD.COM) running successfully. Now, I need to add the other VMs into this domain. How do I do that?

For AlwaysOn, all nodes must in a domain. So, for that to happen, all nodes need to be added to the domain created by the DC. When I go to My Computer >> Properties >> Computer Name >> Change Settings >> Computer Name (tab) >> Change >>

[image: Add Computer to Doamin]

I can change the computer name, but could not add the VM to the domain. What is missing?

This is the error I get:
[image]
I have the following network properties for each VM.

Domain Controller has 1 NIC

1. First:

   - Name: AD
   - Type: Host-Only Adapter
   - Static IP Address (of VM): 200.201.202.1

What IP address settings do I need to configure for VM's to be able to join the domain? I have 3 nodes (VMs)

After @Phil comments, I removed the 200.201.xx.xx IP and added 192.168.1.x IP address pattern.

Thanks,
    _UB

Comment: Can your server see (ping) the Domain Controller?  Also, can it hit the DNS server?

Comment: It cannot ping either of them. DNS server? I do not remember configuring one.

Comment: It would help if you could suggest a proper NIC configuration necessary for this to work?

Comment: I believe a DNS server is a requirement for a domain.  Either way, without seeing the DC a server won't be able to join the domain.

Comment: 200.201.202.1 is a proper internet routeable address. Did you mean to use that? If not, best to use 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x or 172.16.x.x as those are reserved for local use. Making sure your VM server software networking config aligns with all of this, obviously

Comment: I just checked, DNS is instaled as part of configuring DC. But how do I make other VMs see DNS? It has something to do with Network Adapter settings, but not sure what exactly !!

Comment: In the settings of the network adapter, there is a place to put the IP Address of the DNS server.  It's where you configure a static IP, subnet mask, etc.

Comment: Thanks Thomas & Phil. I changes the IP address of DC to 192.168.x.x. And pointed the VMs to the new IP. On the VM, in Network Adapter Settings, I selected 'Obtain IP address automatically' and for DNS server address, I put in the IP address of the Domain Controller IP (which also has DNS). IP address of the DC is 192.168.1.10. But after all this, the VMs are not able to join the domain. I get the same error as shown in the original post above. Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: When I try to ping from VM, I get this error *'PING: transmit failure, General failure'*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some reading more articles on Windows and AD Networking and speaking with abunch of people, this is what helped.

Settings on DC machine:

**IP:**                  192.168.1.10
**Subnetmask:**          255.255.255.0
**Gateway:** (none)

**Preferred DNS:** 127.0.0.1
**Alternate DNS:** (none)

On Each VM:

**IP:**                  192.168.1.11  (/12/13.../15 - on each node)
**Subnetmask:**          255.255.255.0
**Gateway:** (none)

**Preferred DNS:** 192.168.1.10
**Alternate DNS:** (none)

Restart the Network Adapter. BOOM !!

Now I can ping the DC and add them to the domain.

Why does it work now (but not before):

For DC: I made the DNS as loopback IP as preferred DNS (rather than its own IP - 192.168.1.10). This way it knows that the machine itself is the DNS.

For VMs: Gave them valid static IPs, rather than dynamic IP. Set the DNS to the DC (this was set correctly even before).

Glad I learnt something new,
_UB